# The relationship between degree and the number of leaves of a tree?

Tags: graphs, trees, network-topology

What is the relationship between $\text{deg}(T)$ and the number of leaves of $T$, if $T$ is a tree?

Comment: What is $\deg(T)$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus degree of the tree.

Comment: @NinjaBug How is the degree of a tree defined?

Comment: @Juho G = (V, E) is our graph. v is an element of V. deg(v) is the number of adjacent nodes to node v. deg(G) = max(deg(v)) for all v. G is a tree in our case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said the degree of a tree, probably $T$ is a rooted tree. Hence, the relation between the number of leaves $n$ is $\text{deg}(T) \leq n$, as each child of the root is terminated to at least one leaf